# Are these two conditions equivalent?

Tags: c++

Doing input operations before the stream is returned is an idiomatic C++ technique. It looks something like this:

```
while (in >> var)
```

or

```
while (std::getline(in, line))
```

But when these two functions return, they return a reference to the stream, which results in something like this:

```
while (in)
```

Then `operator bool()` is invoked which checks `!fail()`. This is my question. Since `!fail()` only checks `failbit` or `badbit` and not `eofbit`, then how is this safe? Can't the `eofbit` be set in the stream without either `failbit` or `badbit` set and the condition still pass?

For example, the following works:

```
is.setstate(ios_base::eofbit);

if (is)
    std::cout << "It works";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reach the end of the file, `eofbit` is set.  If `eofbit` is set, and a read operation is attempted, `failbit` is set. Therefore, if a read operation is attempted after reaching the end of the file, `failbit` is set, which explains why the "read until end of file" idiom works.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do something like `while ((in >> var).good())`? That way the entire stream state is checked and we return *before* we attempt to unsuccessfully read after hitting EOF.

Comment: @templateboy: One of two things could happen with that.  Either insufficient data remains in the stream, in which case `eofbit` and `failbit` are both set, and it is exactly equivalent to `while(in >> var)`, **or** there is exactly enough data to read successfully into the variable and yet reach the end of the file, in which case you fail to process the last piece of data (even though you successfully read it).